# How to iterate through a specific key-value pair in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration, key-value

I am working with a JSON object that consists of 250+ arrays (data related to different countries like population, language, currency etc.) I need a particular key-value pair (country code) to be pulled out of each array and stored in a different variable so I could use it for something else later.

I have tried using forEach method but I don't have a lot of experience with it so I haven't succeeded. After googling similar questions I found that people are usually asking how to iterate though all key/value pairs and not a specific one like in this case.

```
$.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function(callback) { 
    var isoCode = callback[5].alpha2Code;
    console.log(isoCode);
});
```

The code above pulls out the alpha2code (country code) for a specific array ([5] in this example). Which is the goal, but I need to somehow automate the process so it goes through all 250 arrays, pulls all the country codes and stores them in separate variable.

Comment: You need to map the callback to get your results. [MDN Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example #1

Try something like that:

```js
$.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all", function (data) {
    const codes = data.map(item => item.alpha2Code);
    console.log(codes); // ['AF', 'AX', '...']
});
```

Above code were use jQuery — **mature JS library**.

---

### Example #2

The same scenario, but **in a modern way**, which use Fetch API, based on Promise will look like:

```js
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then((response) => {
        // Parse string to JS object
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        const codes = data.map(item => item.alpha2Code);
        console.log(codes); // ['AF', 'AX', '...']
    });
```

---

### Example #3

**Clean Code version** will be look like:

```js
const config = {
    countriesUrl: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
};

async function makeRequest(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}

function fetchCounties() {
    return makeRequest(config.countriesUrl);
}

async function main() {
    try {
        const countries = await fetchCounties()
        const codes = countries.map(item => item.alpha2Code);
        console.log(codes); // ['AF', 'AX', '...']
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I appreciate you showing me the modern solution - something for me to research. Thanks

Comment: No problem @Rogozin ;-) When you refresh, you will see clean code version.

Comment: You can also use promises with jQuery. `$.getJSON("...").then(data => data.map(item => item.alpha2Code))`

Comment: Awesome @3limin4t0r, but we have Promise in our browsers since 2015 :)

Comment: My point is, if you're already using jQuery there is no need to reinvent the wheel while you create methods. There is no reason to create your own version of `$.getJSON` when you can simply `let data = await $.getJSON("...")`